# Não consigo declarar um cursor no MySql

Tags: mysql

Tenho que fazer uma pesquisa de como funciona cursores pra apresentar na faculdade, em todos os vídeos que vejo no youtube as pessoas declaram dessa forma :

```
declare cur _nome cursor for select a.* from computador as a;
```

porém por alguma razão meu workbench não me deixa utilizar dessa forma, e não encontro na internet qual é a forma correta, todo mundo usa assim !!!

[image: Erro no Workbench]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde.
Segue um exemplo de criação de uma `PROCEDURE` com `CURSOR`, basicamente uma receita de bolo. Não se esqueça de sempre se atentar à troca de delimitador antes da criação de qualquer `TRIGGER`, `PROCEDURE` ou `FUNCTION`.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pr_exemplo_cursor;

DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE pr_exemplo_cursor()
BEGIN

  DECLARE Id INT;
  DECLARE Name VARCHAR(80);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, Name FROM users;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
            IF done THEN

                LEAVE read_loop;

            ELSE

                    SELECT 'DENTRO DO LAÇO DE REPETIÇÃO';

            END IF;

            FETCH cur1 INTO Id, Name;
    END LOOP;
  close cur1;


END$
```

Recomendo você dar uma olhada nesse [curso de MySQL](https://www.udemy.com/bancos-de-dados-relacionais-basico-avancado/), ele aborda muito bem a maioria dos tópicos.

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro já está te avisando o motivo, não se pode usar um `declare` sem um `begin` antes. Exemplo:

```
begin
  DECLARE teste CHAR(16);
```

--Atualização--

Só se pode utilizar cursores se eles estiverem dentro de uma procedure, function ou trigger. Como você não está declarando nenhum desses tipos o erro ocorre. Exemplo de como deveria ser:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureTeste()
BEGIN
  declare cur _nome cursor for select a.* from computador as a;
END
```

Comment: Foi o que eu pensei, porem ao adicionar o codigo entre o begin e o end o erro persiste

Comment: Amigo, use `DELIMITER $` para alterar o delimitador antes da criação da `PROCEDURE`